# Rector PHP: What rule can I use to remove a function call?

Tags: php, rules, rector

I have code like this:

```
$x = (int) trim(fuzzy_logic(floor($x1 / $x2)));
$t = fuzzy_logic([$title,$desc]);
$z = trim(fuzzy_logic($z));
$i = fuzzy_logic($i);
```

The function **fuzzy_logic()** have been obsolete, and I would like to have it removed. How would I go about for making a [Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) rule for removing it so that my code becomes:

```
$x = (int) trim(floor($x1 / $x2));
$t = [$title,$desc];
$z = trim($z);
$i = $i;
```

I looked in the documentation and found a way of removing a function entirely, which is not the case for me here as I only want it removed and keep whatever parameter thats inside.

Rector rule for removing entire function: [RemoveFuncCallRector.php](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/main/rules/Removing/Rector/FuncCall/RemoveFuncCallRector.php)